# Search by zip-code (Postleitzahl) and cityname (Germany)

Tags: php, search, city

I have a question concerning a search fiel on my website. I want to let the user search for a city in germany. Currently i am using the 'odgbPLZnearby' i found online. This outputs other zip-codes within a given distance of the entered zip-code. Currently i use a  to enter the zip-code.

Now i want to expand the feature so the user can also enter the name of the city or zip-code and city. I suppose i have to modify how the input is handled, but i do not know how.

How do i hanlde the different cases of:

- zip-code only
- city name only
- zip-code + city
- city + zip-code
- one of them is entered incorrenctly
- typos
- city + zip-code dont match
- added commas (e.g. "56068 Koblenz" / "56068, Koblenz")
- different versions of citynames (e.g.: "Lauf a. d. Pegnitz" / "Lauf an der Pegnitz")

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: You can try and create you own code for this, i do not know if there are libraries that already solve this

Comment: i pobably could write my own code if i know how to separate the zip-code from the cityname. Not sure how to handle a flexible user-input like that.

Comment: you can put two input, one for zip and one for city. (with autocomplete maybe). And you can accept only numbers in the first one( i do not know how the german zip code is).

Comment: German zip-code is numbers only. Splitting the input in two fields didnt test well, and users always put the wrong information in the fields. It is a good idea though, i'll pick it up. Got any tips on auto-correct? If it is somehow possible i would like to have it feel more like google-search in one input field than a very restricted form with several fields. ;)

Comment: example 1 .> https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/ , example 2 -> http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/